# php - only last result from api request

Tags: php, arrays, curl

I get some data from a api but i'm justing looking to get the most recent data.

When i print_r the data it look likes this:

```
Array
(
    [curlResult] => Rank,Club,Country,Level,Elo,From,To
None,Ajax,NED,1,1069.13220215,1956-07-01,1956-09-02
None,Ajax,NED,1,1074.29101562,1956-09-03,1956-09-09
None,Ajax,NED,1,1084.49816895,1956-09-10,1956-09-23
None,Ajax,NED,1,1091.4354248,1956-09-24,1956-09-30 //this one
)
```

This goes on for thousands of results, but i only need te last line (most recent). So if the result would have been the above i want to get all the data from the line that has "//this one" behind it.

This is the code i use to get the data:

```
<?php
function makeRequest($url, $callDetails = false)
{
  // Set handle
  $ch = curl_init($url);

  // Set options
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

  // Execute curl handle add results to data return array.
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  $returnGroup = ['curlResult' => $result,];

  // If details of curl execution are asked for add them to return group.
  if ($callDetails) {
    $returnGroup['info'] = curl_getinfo($ch);
    $returnGroup['errno'] = curl_errno($ch);
    $returnGroup['error'] = curl_error($ch);
  }

  // Close cURL and return response.
  curl_close($ch);
  return $returnGroup;
}

$url = "http://api.website.com/Ajax";/* some url */
$response = makeRequest($url);

// $csv = array_map('str_getcsv', $response);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($response);

?>
```

Comment: That `print_r` looks confusing... From what I can see, the API returns it all as comma delimited?

Comment: Hard to imagine that an api only serves thousands of results, you should check if there are settings to manipulate the number of results.

Comment: Can you confirm that the data is a Newline delimited, comma seperated string? Although this question should probably give you all the clues to a solution you need

Comment: You could simply `explode` the string at `\n` and take the last element of the resulting array, or did you already try that?

Comment: since its array its pretty simple.. get the array.length suppose its 100; then to get that last data just do $response[array.length-1]. It will give you the last array and that is you last result

Comment: @JustCarty Jep. RiggsFolly Yeah it is, you're answer gave me some ideas on in what direction to look! Gonna try. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having located your API online I was able to create this answer for you:

```
$resp = makeRequest('http://api.clubelo.com/Wolves')['curlResult'];
$result = array_filter(explode("\n", $resp), function ($record) {
    return !empty($record);
});

$headings = explode(',', reset($result));
$record = explode(',', end($result));

$last = array_combine($headings, $record);
```

`$resp` is made up of the function call and then I instantly access the result of the cURL operation.

`$result` uses the [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function to separate every line of the API response into its own 'record'.

`$headings` and `$record` just split the API response into their respective 'fields'.
[`reset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) is a PHP function that resets the internal pointer to the start of an array and returns that item.
[`end`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) is the opposite of `reset` and will set the internal pointer to the end of the array and return that item.

`$last` will be the last record from the API with the `$headings` set as the array keys with the value being the respective value from the response.

It's out of your control, but this API could be served *a lot* better! Most of this code is making the response presented *sensibly*.

Comment: Thank you. This is perfect!